# How do I get rid of these thread errors in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm having some problems with this program I'm making in C++. For what I'm doing here:

```
{
    GridWorld world;
    string input = "";

    while (input != "q")
    {
        thread render(&GridWorld::Render, GridWorld());
        render.join();

        input = world.GetInput();

        thread thread_update(&GridWorld::Update, GridWorld());

        thread_update.join();

    }

    cout << "Thank you for playing\n";
}
```

[I get these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaLue.png)

It used to work before, but now it is not anymore.

Can someone please help

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Creating a thread and then immediately joining it is pointless. In the posted code just call the functions directly and remove the threading.

Comment: also check your compiler compilers the minimal example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10673671/1505939

Comment: @RichardCritten presumably this is a minimalized example of some more complicated case that won't join immediately, to isolate the error message

Comment: What does `GridWorld` look like?  We need a [mre].

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using lambda expressions?

```
...
thread render([]() { GridWorld().Render(); });
...
thread thread_update([]() { GridWorld().Update(); });
...
```

Or maybe

```
...
thread render([&world]() { world.Render(); });
...
thread thread_update([&world]() { world.Update(); });
...
```