# Using threads on class methods C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, std

I'm trying to use a thread on a method of a class I created.
The thread supposes to read the content of the file into a queue.

Here are the methods:

```cpp
void MessageSender::readAdminFile()
{
    std::queue<std::string> messageQueue;

    std::thread t(getMassage, std::ref(messageQueue));
    t.join();
}

void MessageSender::getMassage(std::queue<std::string>& messageQueue)
{   
    while (true)
    {
        mtx.lock();
        std::ifstream db;
        std::string line, massage;
        db.open(MSFILE);
        if (db.is_open())
        {
            while (std::getline(db, line))
            {
                massage.append(line + "\n");
            }
            std::cout << massage;
            messageQueue.push(massage);
        }
        mtx.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));
    }
}
```

**Errors:**

- `Error (active)   E0289   no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list`
- `Error    C3867   'MessageSender::getMassage': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

Comment: What is the problem that you have encountered? Edit your question and add more info on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to make a thread from a member function? Then this would be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10673585/14215102

Comment: "getMassage" yes, I also need one :-)

Comment: You shoud [edit] and show a [mcve].